# Refresh map to show current location after enabling GPS setting

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

My app will showing marker on current location. GPS setting alert dialog will showing if GPS was disabled. After enabling GPS and back to the application, the map not refreshing. So I must force stop my app and open again. How to refreshing the map activity ?

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        ViewMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void ViewMap() {
    if(googleMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

            TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
            locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
        }
        else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ViewMap();
}
```

Comment: Override the method on location change. It will give to updated lat long value.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click to refresh button after turn on your gps then get the current lat long value and

```
MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(current lat, current long).title("Your title if required");

Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
marker.showInfoWindow();

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(current lat, current long).zoom(12).build();

mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have refresh button. I want my map refresh itself.

Comment: then call you refresh method from onLocationChange() override method and send the current lat long value.